# excel macro - need to extract information only after given string

Tags: excel, data-extraction, vba

I'm looking for a solution to extract some information from cells in a spreadsheet, and dump it into the adjacent column. Each cell contains a lot of junk, but always ends with the pattern "WX=" followed only by the information I would like to extract. The length of the information I would like is usually between 7-10 alphanumeric characters. Are there any functions that can already do this, or do I need an entirely unique script to acheive this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function below will return the string after "WX=" from cell `A1`:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - (FIND("WX=", A1) + 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot get this to apply to an entire column. Is this because only some of the cells contain the string? I have replaced all A1, with A:A, but not getting the desired result. As you can see, I'm a bit of a beginner...

Comment: If you have written the code above in, say, cell `B1` then you should drag the function down along side the content in column `A`. This way the value in cell `B2` will find the string from cell `A2`, `B3` will look in `A3` and so forth.

Comment: How embarrassing. I've been out of work for months now, and even forgot such simple things! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VBA `Mid` function **if you are doing this in VBA**:

```
Mid(Range("A1"), 4)
```

Syntax is:

```
Mid(text, start_character, number_of_characters)
```

This will return the middle `number_of_characters` unless that argument is omitted, in which case it returns the remainder of the string, from the specified `start_character` position.

So if cell `A1` contains a string like `wx=kladlkjad;kjadsfkjasfd` then:

```
Mid(Range("A1"), 4, 4)
```

Would return: `klad`, whereas

```
Mid(Range("A1"), 4)
```

Would return `kladlkjad;kjadsfkjasfd`

The `Mid` function works differently if you are doing it as a WorksheetFunction, in which case the `number_of_characters` is **NOT** an optional parameter, and you would have to use the `Right` function and `Len` function as the Soren indicates.